# chart js barchart with uneven time interval datapoints, parsed from django date time

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I'm having trouble parsing Date Times from django in a way that would make chart.js display the data points (as bars) in uneven time intervals that match their distance from one another. Right now the bars are always equidistant from one another. Also I would like to display the time stamps in the format HH:mm.

I've tried 1)

```
new Date("{{ d.isoformat }}")
```

which outputs:
Thu May 20 2021 04:28:31 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)

and 2)

```
new Date("{{ d.isoformat }}").toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'})
```

which outputs
04:28 AM

So I'm probably parsing them incorrectly in charts.js with parser: 'HH:mm', and I don't know how to do it correctly in either case. Both options result in equidistant bars.

HTML/javascript:

```
var db_labels = [];
{% for d in x_val %}
db_labels.push(new Date("{{ d.isoformat }}").toLocaleTimeString(navigator.language, {hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'}));
{% endfor %}

var graphData = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: db_labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'PM2.5',
            data: db_y,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(73, 198, 230, 0.5)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [{
             type: 'time',
             time: {
               parser: 'HH:mm',
               format: 'HH:mm',
               tooltipFormat: 'HH:mm',
               unit: 'minute',
               unitStepSize: 15,
               displayFormats: {
                 'minute': 'HH:mm',
                 'hour': 'HH:mm'
               },
             }
         }]
        },
    }
}
```

I get this kind of a graph currently with the above code:
[equidistant bar graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjMWK.png)